# crop UIImage to mask

Tags: swift, uiimage

I have a UIImage that contains a mask of another UIImage. The only problem is when I tap the area outside the mask, the script still thinks I'm tapping the image.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleTap(_:)))
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

let imageMask = UIImageView()
imageMask.image = ...//Image to mask to
imageMask.frame = imageView.bounds

imageView = UIImageView(image: ...)
imageView.mask = imageMask

imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("hello")
    //prints "hello" when tapped Image outside of mask
}
```

How to I completely crop the image to the mask, so It won't register taps outside of the mask?

Comment: could you post the code of the gesture recognizer?

Comment: You could crop imageView frame, but I can't understand what you mean about "won't register taps outside of the mask"!

Comment: Yes I add gesture recognizer code @excitedmicrobe

Comment: I basically want to crop the entire image to the mask, so that you can only tap on the mask and not the area outside of the mask @FrancescoDestino

Comment: Oh wonderful! So you should use a simple UIView with userInteractionEnabled = true and add the imageView cropped as a subview; so the compiler will trigger only the tapGesture of your imageCropped

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead two imageViews

```
let overMask = UIView()
overMask.frame = imageView.bounds
overMask.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

imageView = UIImageView(image: ...)
imageView.mask = overMask

imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

overMask.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: when I try `imageView.crop()` I get `Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'crop';`

Comment: and when I run the code without `.crop()` it's the same result of my original code

Comment: Yeah sorry i didn't tell you that this should be a new function to crop the imageView :)
You should create a new function called crop.
How you want to crop the imageView? You want to make a circle? Ora anything else?

Comment: I want to crop the imageView to the shape of the mask.